# Adding custom html and css in TinyMCE

Tags: html, css, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I'm using TinyMCE and I would like to add custom html/css to the output. All the bullet lists created in the Tiny editor should have these css classes and an `<i>` tag like this:

```
<ul class="iconlist">
    <li><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Item 1</li>
    <li><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way I can make Tiny output this exact html for all bullet lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDITED: I have amended this answer to respond to comments from OP*

You can apply custom CSS to editor content using either the `content_css` or `content_style` configuration options:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style

Many Tiny implementers use this to apply the same CSS to in-editor content as will be applied to that content when it is later rendered elsewhere, outside of the editor.

However, to make the icons appear as expected within the editor, you will also need to configure the editor to allow for empty `<i>` elements. Empty `<i>` elements are by default removed from the editor. You can change this behavior by using the `extended_valid_elements:` configuration option:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements

```
extended_valid_elements: 'i[*]',
```

All of this will allow external icon libraries that utilize `<i>` elements to function in TinyMCE (short of the specific setup each individual library may require).

*Edited to Add:*

> how do I even configure Tiny so that it always adds the `<i>` element after an `<li>` element?

One approach is to use a node filter on TinyMCE's serializer to add `<i>` elements as the first child of `<li>` elements. Here is a Tiny Fiddle example (using Font Awesome icons):

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/R4haab

Documentation:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.serializer/#addnodefilter

The serializer is used when taking the content inside the editor (i.e. DOM nodes) and then converting that back to a string based HTML representation. So it's run on calls such as `getContent()`. This means that the `<i>` element is not added in realtime, as list elements are inserted, but will be added to any/all `<li>` elements (that don't already have it) whenever the serializer is run, including when saves are triggered, or when the form containing TinyMCE is POSTed.

Comment: I realize that was unclear: it does not matter what style the content has in the editor itself. I just want the resulting html output from the editor to be the way I described.

Comment: Regarding the elements, I understand that I need to configure to allow empty <i> elements, but how do I even configure Tiny so that it always adds the <i> element after an <li> element?

Comment: I have edited my answer to respond to this feedback. let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Your fiddle worked like a charm, thanks! :o) Just one more thing: I if you look at my original code example, the <ul> tag needs a class too, which means that I have to add multiple values for extended_valid_elements: `'ul[class=iconlist]'` and `'i[*]'`. However, I can't find anywhere in the docs how you add multiple values, surrounding with { [ ( don't work. I'm guessing there is a really simple answer to this, but I can't find it.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: `'ul[class=iconlist], i[*]'` Thanks again!